# Assign a tag to a button and retrieve it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have some buttons built at run-time, and I want to assign a tag for each of the buttons.

I do it so

```
private void CreateCategory(DataTable dt)
{
     int top = 0;
     int left = 0;
     string color = "";

     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         //  MessageBox.Show(row["Denumire"].ToString());
         //       List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>(); 

         Button btnCategorie = new Button();                
         color = row["Culoare"].ToString();
         btnCategorie.Text = row["Denumire"].ToString();
         btnCategorie.BackColor = rbgToColor(color);
         btnCategorie.Top = 0 + top;
         btnCategorie.Left = 0 + left;
         btnCategorie.Width = 120;
         btnCategorie.Height = 120;
         btnCategorie.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
         btnCategorie.Tag =  Int16.Parse(row["IDSubcategorie"].ToString());
         //   buttons.Add(newButton);                    
         tabCategorii.Controls.Add(btnCategorie);
         btnCategorie.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnCategorii_Click);
         left = left + 120;
         if (left % 600 == 0) 
         { 
              top = top + 120;
              left = 0;
         }
    }
}
```

Now I've tried to retrieve it like this

```
DataTable dtProducts  = new DataTable();
dtProducts = LoadProducts((int)(sender as Button).Tag);         
CreateProducts( dtProducts, (sender as Button).BackColor, pnlProduse);
```

This throws an error when trying to convert

```
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
```

I've managed to do it, but it looks like a hack, and i don't like it, is there a better way to retrieve my tag value?

```
 dtProducts = LoadProducts(Int32.Parse((sender as Button).Tag.ToString()));
```

Comment: I assume this is attached to a form? What you've shown will work, but you may want to store your ID in a hidden form field instead of relying on the button Tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to cast an `Int16` to and `int` (aka `Int32`).

An `Int16` is a `short` and `Int32` is `int`, also `Int64` is a `long`.

Try either putting in an `Int32` or pulling out an `Int16`:

Pull out as `Int16`:

```
dtProducts = LoadProducts((Int16)(sender as Button).Tag);
```

Or put in as `Int32`:

```
btnCategorie.Tag =  Int32.Parse(row["IDSubcategorie"].ToString());
```

You only need one of the above, not both otherwise you have the same problem as before.

I'd recommend using `Int32` / `int` for everything, unless you have a specific need for `Int16` - in this day and age of computing, you're not going to get much benefit.

Comment: Thank you, i missed that detail.